# Stormpath multi-tenant express

Tags: node.js, stormpath, express-stormpath

i am trying to learn how to make a multi-tenant app with stormpath and node with express. This is the [official](http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/multi-tenant/) document on that topic. As for now i am using [express-stormpath](https://github.com/stormpath/express-stormpath) lib to make my login and stuff. But i can not find how i do the multi-tenant.

**UPDATE**
I got it to work with passport stormpath strategy. I do not know if that is the right way but it works... The problem now is how do i change accountStore dynamic in the express version? It feels like a public declared variable is not so good?

```
var href = {
  href: null
}

function hrefUrl(req, res, next){
  var host = req.headers.host;
  var account = host.split(".")[0];

  spClient.getDirectories(function (err, directories) {
    directories.each(function (dir, cb){
      if(account.toLowerCase() == dir.name.toLowerCase()){
        href.href = dir.href
      }
      cb();
    }, function (err){
      if(href.href == null){
        return res.redirect(301, 'http://dashboard.local.dev/selectCompany');
      }
      next();
    });
  });
}

// Authenticate a user.
router.post('/login', hrefUrl, passport.authenticate('stormpath',
    {
      successRedirect: '/dashboard',
      failureRedirect: '/login',
      failureFlash: 'Invalid email or password.',
      accountStore: href
    }
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express-stormpath has provided APIs for you to access account information in your application. These accounts belong to directories. From the official document, you have two solutions to support multi-tenant. One is to create group per tenant, and another is to create directory per tenant.

For either solution you choose, you would have to use the APIs provided by express-stormpath to access these information associated with an account.

For example if you have created different directories for each tenant, you may need to add your business logics regarding to the multi-tenant in the [`postLoginHandler`](https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/latest/login.html#post-login-handler).

```js
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
    postLoginHandler: function (account, req, res, next) {
        account.getDirectory(function(err, directory) {
            console.log(directory)
            // if directory is tenant-1
            // if directory is tenant-2
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But i am still stuck...
This is how i created in the stormpath admin:
One application: APP1.
Created two directories: CompanyA, CompanyB
In APP1 account stores i added CompanyA and B. CompanyA is set as "DEFAULT ACCOUNT LOCATION". Now i create 3 users.
`User1 in ComapyA
User2 in ComapyB
User2 in ComapyA`
The problem i have now is it will only show CompanyA...

Comment: This my be the case way it only list one. "During a login attempt to the application, Stormpath will access account stores in order of priority."

Comment: How did you create your users? Where did you see that it only show CopmanyA?